# Using C-x C-<left|right> for windmove

Tags: key-bindings, osx

On a Mac, using Emacs 26.1, I'd like to bind my `windmove` functions using:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-<left>")  'windmove-left)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-<right>") 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-<up>")    'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-<down>")  'windmove-down)
```

`"C-x C-<up>"` and `"C-x C-<down>"` work, but for some reason the left and right ones don't. When I use `describe-key` on them, it seems I can't even enter those key sequences (i.e. it stops echoing after "C-x", and does not respond to the rest of the input). I also tried the syntax `"C-x <C-left>"`, to no avail.

Comment: Sounds like Emacs is not seeing those keys at all. Check your window manager or OS, to see if it intercepts them for something else. And the best syntax to use with `kbd` is the one you see when you use `C-h k`. When I try that for such keys I see `C-x <C-left>`, `C-x <C-up>`, etc.

Comment: That's exactly it @Drew, thanks! https://superuser.com/a/638725/195605 is the answer. If you want to push your comment into an answer, I will set it as the one.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear: the problem in my particular case was the fact the Mac Mission Control app was preempting the `Ctrl + left|right` keys; once I disabled it, the keys began available to Emacs. Both kbd syntaxes seem to work equally fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Emacs is not seeing those keys at all. Check your window manager or OS, to see if it intercepts them for something else.

And the best syntax to use with `kbd` is the one you see when you use `C-h k`. When I try that for such keys I see `C-x <C-left>`, `C-x <C-up>`, etc.  (But your question says that you already tried `C-x <C-left>`, so I guess that's not the problem.)

Comment: In my particular case I had to disable Mission Control shortcuts in the OSX System Preferences, as described there: https://superuser.com/a/638725/195605